# Can I have a core data attribute decorated with readonly in the interface and then readwrite in the implementation?

Tags: ios, core-data

In my NSManagedObject subclass I want to specify a particular attribute as readonly in the interface but readwrite in the implementation. I have done this before with other classes. But the Core Data generated subclasses use @dynamic in the implementation and it seems like I can't add the readwrite decorator to @dynamic like can be done with @property.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the property in the header file as `readonly` and then provide your own implementation for the setter in the implementation:

(using ARC)

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString * name;

- (void)changeName;

@end

@implementation Person

@dynamic name;

- (void)changeName
{
    self.name = @"Test";
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)name
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:name forKey:@"name"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Comment: Worked but Xcode wouldn't autocomplete setName: after I added the readonly decorator. If I added the setter first and then the decorator it worked as expected.

Comment: You can de re-declare the property as readwrite in the implementation file, using a class extension.

Comment: @MartinR How would this be done? `@dynamic` doesn't seem to accept any decorators.

Comment: @MurraySagal: You write `@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString * name;` in a *Class Extension* in the implementation file  Person.m.